# recursion and memory usage in it

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

i recently saw a question which req. to reverse a stack in O(1) space.

1) stack is not necessarily of an array ... we can't access index.
2)number of elements are not known.

i came up with below code and it is working but `not convinced that it is O(1) space because i have declared "int temp" exactly n times`, suppose there are initially n elements in stack)`so it has taken O(n) space.`

please tell i am right or not and is there a better way to find the solution?.

code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
stack<int>st;
void rec()
{
    if(st.empty()) 
        return;
    int temp=st.top();
    st.pop();

    rec();
    st.push(temp);
}
int main()
{
    st.push(1);
    st.push(2);
    st.push(3);
    st.push(4);

    rec();
}
```

Comment: yes - I think you're using O(n) space with this solution.

Comment: You are correct that this is `O(n)` space, but I wouldn't know how else to do this with `O(1)` space. The only way to get the bottom element from the stack is to first get off the others, which you need to store somewhere. The only place to store them, respecting the constant space requirement, is on your initial stack, but then you cannot reach the last element... I would say your solution is the one they meant in the question, but they didn't realize that the recursion also uses a stack of `O(n)` size...

Comment: you are creating n stack frames with the recursive calls anyway even without the int temp if I'm correct

Comment: If you'll pop element from one stack and push them into another - _maybe_ it will be O(1) in terms of memory (if stack implemented as e.g. linked list). This theory, however, have very few touchpoints with practice.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk i am concerned only with initialization of `temp variable.` as far as `creating n stack frames` are concerned i think we can pass stack as reference and avoid it ?

Comment: @anon: here I mean that each of your rec() call creates a *call stack* frame (not to be mistaken with the "st" stack in your program), each taking up some memory. The question is whether or not you take that memory into account when saying O(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build 2 stacks **"back to back"** in a single array with n elements.  Basically stack #1 is a "normal" stack, and stack #2 grows "downwards" from the end of the array.

Whenever the 2 stacks together contain all n elements, there is no gap between them, so for example popping an element from stack #1 and immediately pushing it onto stack #2 in this situation can be accomplished without even moving any data: just move the `top` pointer for stack #1 down, and the `top` pointer for stack #2 *physically* down (but *logically* up).

Suppose we start with all elements in stack #1.  Now you can pop all of them except the last one, immediately pushing each onto stack #2.  The last element you can pop off and store in a temporary place x (O(1) extra storage, which we are allowed).  Now pop all n-1 items in stack #2, pushing each in turn back onto stack #1, and then finally push x back onto (the now-empty) stack *#2*.  At this point, we have succeeded in deleting the bottom element in stack #1, and putting it at the top of (well, it's the only element in) stack #2.

Now just recurse: pretend we only have n-1 items, and solve *this* smaller problem.  Keep recursing until all elements have been pushed onto stack #2 in reverse order.  In one final step, pop each of them off and push them back onto stack #1.

All in all, O(n^2) steps are required, but we manage with just O(1) space.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of is to write your own stack using a linked list and then swap the head/tail pointers and a "direction" indicator which tells your routine to go forward or backwards when you push/pop.  Any other way I can think of would be O(n).

If you know upper limit of n you can also use an array/index instead of a list.

Whether it makes sense to do so is probably dependent on the reason for doing so and the language.